# Prevent containers from using hugepages

Tags: docker

How do I prevent applications in containers from using hugepages? I want to allocate large 1G hugepages for VMs, but these are currently "stolen" by applications that do not need them at all (like phpmyadmin).

I found the capability `CAP_IPC_LOCK`:

> Allocate memory using huge pages (memfd_create(2), mmap(2), shmctl(2)).

but Docker containers already [don't have this capability by default](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities).

Is it possible to deny containers access to hugepages?